# I accidentally went to Siri settings and changed the info to "Cassie" one of my contacts that isn't me.

Tags: siri

I accidentally went to Siri settings and changed the info to "Cassie" one of my contacts that isn't me. I don't want her knowing any info at all. I can't get rid of the contact so it could go back to nothing. How do I get it to go back to where she doesn't know any info?

Can someone help me?? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

**What you can do is:**

1. Make a blank contact
2. Tell Siri you are the blank contact (Set My Info as blank contact)
3. Delete the blank contact

That should remove the contact from 'My Info'

**To make a new contact:**

1. Open the Contacts App
2. Touch the Plus sign at the top

**To delete a contact:**

1. Open the Contacts App
2. Select the contact you want to delete
3. Press 'Edit' at the top right
4. Scroll all the way down and press delete